# jQuery: how do i set one "a" tag with preventdefault and one without?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1 link surrounding another one like this:

```
<a href="#" class="video-link">
  <a href="#" class="not-video-link">link</a>
</a>
```

with jQuery i have found a function that can transform a table to iframe like this:

```
$(".video-link").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Capture the link's HREF attribute in a variable. 
    var youtubeLink = $(this).attr('href');
    var youtubeDiv = $(this).attr('id');

    // Set the HTML (the content) of the "video destination div" 
    // to = your iframe, including the youtubeLink
    // that the user original saved into this node.

    $('#' + youtubeDiv + '').html('<iframe style="margin-left:-12px; margin-right:-12px;" frameborder="0" height="234" src="' + youtubeLink + '&autoplay=1" title="YouTube video player" width="418"></iframe>');
});
```

It works fine but i need to get the other "a" tag to work as normal.

the second link has `class="not-video-link"` and i want that to open a link as normal.

Here is the whole box:

```
        echo '<br />
        <div id="the-video-destination-div'.$id.'"  class="video-link" href="'.youtubelink(tolink($youtubevid)).'">
        <table style="background-color:#EDEFF4; font-size:11px; border:1px solid #ccc;">
        <tr><td><a ><img style="cursor:pointer;" align="left" src="'.$video_thumbnail.'" width="152px" height="114px" /></a></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; width:199px; padding:5px; cursor:default; " ><font style="color: #3B5998; text-decoration:none; font-weight: bold;"><font class="youtube-title"><a id="not-video-link" style="cursor:pointer;" href1="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.youtubetitle($wallrow["youtubevid"]).'" target="_blank">'.$video_title.'</a></font></font><font class="link-host"><br /><a href="http://www.youtube.com">www.youtube.com</a><br /><br />'.substr($video_description,0,149).'...</font></td></tr>
        </table></div><br />';
```

I have now changed from div with a href attr inside the div tag. Is that illigal?

I have found a soulution to the problem.

```
                $("a#not-video-link").click(function () {
                var youtubeLink1 = $(this).attr('href1');
                      window.open(youtubeLink1);
                      event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                    });

            $(".video-link").live("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();


                  // Capture the link's HREF attribute in a variable.
                  var youtubeLink = $(this).attr('href');
                  var youtubeDiv = $(this).attr('id');

                  // Set the HTML (the content) of the "video destination div" to = your iframe, including the youtubeLink that the user original saved into this node.
                  $('#' + youtubeDiv + '').html('<iframe style="margin-left:-12px; margin-right:-12px;" frameborder="0" height="234" src="' + youtubeLink + '&autoplay=1" title="YouTube video player" width="418"></iframe>');
                });
```

This makes the link stop the other link to launch and the other way around.

Comment: You should not nest links like that.. it is simply invalid HTML. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

Comment: i have to, it's for youtube iframe creation. If it's not inside the "a" the function will not work.

Comment: @Thayer no you don't. Since you're using preventDefault you can attach the click event to any html-tag

Comment: Even you have in your HTML like that.. Browser would not render it like that.. It would simply create two different links.. You can try http://jsfiddle.net/H44jE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest Links are not allowed and simply considered as invalid construct.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

> **12.2.2 Nested links are illegal**
>
> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A
>   element must not contain any other A elements.
>
> Since the DTD defines the LINK element to be empty, LINK elements may
>   not be nested either.

Since that is the case the browser would not render them as nested.. It would simply create below as 2 different links (See proof / picture).

```
<a href="#" class="video-link">
  <a href="#" class="not-video-link">link</a>
</a>
```

**Proof:** http://jsfiddle.net/H44jE/ [click inspect and click on the links]

Also the construct looked different on different browsers..

[image]

**Note:** I am not sure what you are trying.. but as flec mentioned you should look for other options..

> @Thayer no you don't. Since you're using preventDefault you can attach the click event to any html-tag

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping them as one link and doing all the processing on the single click handler?

That way you will have the best of two worlds of a valid HTML and achieving what you want. For example (based on my understanding of the issue):

```
<a href="#" class="video-link" data-otherHref="#">
  link
</a>
```

And using jquery:

```
$(".video-link").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Capture the link's HREF attribute in a variable. 
    var youtubeLink = $(this).attr('href');
    var youtubeDiv = $(this).attr('id');

    // Set the HTML (the content) of the "video destination div" 
    // to = your iframe, including the youtubeLink
    // that the user original saved into this node.

    $('#' + youtubeDiv + '').html('<iframe style="margin-left:-12px; margin-right:-12px;" frameborder="0" height="234" src="' + youtubeLink + '&autoplay=1" title="YouTube video player" width="418"></iframe>');

    // Here do whatever you want for the second link 
    var otherLink = $(this).data('otherHref');
});
```